# Gtk3 - How to get the index of a widget in it's container?

Tags: c, widget, containers, gtk3

I have pointers to two different widgets which are located in the same container (a GtkBox). I want to use `gtk_box_reorder_child(container, widgetToMove, destinationIndex)` in order to change the container position of one of them to the index of the other:

```
GtkWidget *widgetToMove;
GtkWidget *target;
// Does something like 'gtk_get_container_index' exist ?
gint targetIndex = gtk_get_container_index(target) 
gtk_box_reorder_child (myBox,widgetToMove,targetIndex);
```

... sounds stupid, however after 15 min of search I still dont know how to get the index of a widget in it's container.

**Edit:  Solved, here the solution**

```
GtkWidget *widgetToMove;
GtkWidget *target;
GValue targetIndex = G_VALUE_INIT;
g_value_init (&targetIndex, G_TYPE_INT);
gtk_container_child_get_property(myBox,target,"position",&targetIndex);
gtk_box_reorder_child (myBox,widgetToMove,g_value_get_int(&targetIndex));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Container widgets save a bunch of "child properties" that you can query using [`container.child_get_property`](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-child-get-property).
The property you're looking for is called `position`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was searching for! I'll add some code to the question, since the `child_get_property` is not trivial to use.

Comment: Some containers (e.g. ListBox) don't have a "position" property. [gtk_container_class_list_child_properties](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-class-list-child-properties) will give you the properties available for a given container.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but not enough rep to comment.

Firstly, I'm just going to note that the gtkBox page references a "position" child property, though I will be honest I don't remember how to access properties like that.

What I have done in a similar situation that worked is to create a gtkGrid instead of a gtkBox and use the gtk_grid_get_child_at() method to check each child starting from index of 0,0. You could use a for loop similar to this

```
for(int n=0;n<numChildren;n++)
{
    gtkWidget* temp = gtk_grid_get_child_at(myGrid, n, 0);
    if(temp == myWidget)
        break;
}
//n now holds the index of myWidget in myGrid
```

Comment: Thanks, the "position" property did the trick ... I will add some code to the question, since it is not trivial to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`gtk_container_get_children()`](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-get-children), which returns  [`Glist*`](https://developer-old.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html).
Then you can loop over the list, or, for example, check if your widget is in the list with `g_list_find()`.